# AlerDialog call from other class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to call my alertdialog from another class in same file. Where do i have wrong here? Just trying to extends the AlertDialog, but i'm not sure how to do this, i don't want to be in my public main class, trying that and work but i need to be in separable class if this is possible.

```
class MyDialog extends AlertDialog {
public static Context context;
public static int theme;
protected MyDialog(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);
    MyDialog.context = context;

    theme = THEME_HOLO_DARK;
    MyDialog.theme = theme;
}

public void onCreateAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Auto Start")
    .setMessage("Start playing after: 30 sec")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.info)
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Auto start cancaled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        }
    );
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

I call it from main class like this:

```
Context context = MyDialog.context;
int i = MyDialog.theme;
MyDialog md = new MyDialog(context, i);
md.onCreateAlertDialog();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it comes from the context variable that you didn't initialize it.
You should get it from the activity your are calling the dialog from :

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    ...
    Context context = this;
    MyDialog md = new MyDialog(context, i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You are right, its allays nice to work with this community :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using AlertDialog.Builder which will always return an instance of the AlertDialog class when you build it. You would have to override the static builder to return an instance of your class but this is not really possible.

What you want to do is extend the Dialog class and create your own AlertDialog implementation as demonstrated in the HoloEverywhere library.

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/src/com/WazaBe/HoloEverywhere/app/AlertDialog.java

```
public class AlertDialog extends Dialog implements DialogInterface {
    public static class Builder {
        private final AlertController.AlertParams P;

        public Builder(Context context) {
            this(context, resolveDialogTheme(context, 0));
        }

        public Builder(Context context, int theme) {
            P = new AlertController.AlertParams(new ContextThemeWrapper(
                    context, resolveDialogTheme(context, theme)));
            P.mTheme = theme;
        }

        public AlertDialog create() {
            final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(P.mContext, P.mTheme);
            P.apply(dialog.mAlert);
            dialog.setCancelable(P.mCancelable);
            if (P.mCancelable) {
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            }
            dialog.setOnCancelListener(P.mOnCancelListener);
            if (P.mOnKeyListener != null) {
                dialog.setOnKeyListener(P.mOnKeyListener);
            }
            return dialog;
        }

        public Context getContext() {
            return P.mContext;
        }

        public Builder setAdapter(final ListAdapter adapter,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mAdapter = adapter;
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setCancelable(boolean cancelable) {
            P.mCancelable = cancelable;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setCheckedItem(int checkedItem) {
            P.mCheckedItem = checkedItem;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setCursor(final Cursor cursor,
                final OnClickListener listener, String labelColumn) {
            P.mCursor = cursor;
            P.mLabelColumn = labelColumn;
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setCustomTitle(View customTitleView) {
            P.mCustomTitleView = customTitleView;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setIcon(Drawable icon) {
            P.mIcon = icon;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setIcon(int iconId) {
            P.mIconId = iconId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setIconAttribute(int attrId) {
            TypedValue out = new TypedValue();
            P.mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attrId, out, true);
            P.mIconId = out.resourceId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setInverseBackgroundForced(boolean useInverseBackground) {
            P.mForceInverseBackground = useInverseBackground;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setItems(CharSequence[] items,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mItems = items;
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setItems(int itemsId, final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mItems = P.mContext.getResources().getTextArray(itemsId);
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMessage(CharSequence message) {
            P.mMessage = message;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMessage(int messageId) {
            P.mMessage = P.mContext.getText(messageId);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMultiChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items,
                boolean[] checkedItems,
                final OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener) {
            P.mItems = items;
            P.mOnCheckboxClickListener = listener;
            P.mCheckedItems = checkedItems;
            P.mIsMultiChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMultiChoiceItems(Cursor cursor,
                String isCheckedColumn, String labelColumn,
                final OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener) {
            P.mCursor = cursor;
            P.mOnCheckboxClickListener = listener;
            P.mIsCheckedColumn = isCheckedColumn;
            P.mLabelColumn = labelColumn;
            P.mIsMultiChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMultiChoiceItems(int itemsId, boolean[] checkedItems,
                final OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener) {
            P.mItems = P.mContext.getResources().getTextArray(itemsId);
            P.mOnCheckboxClickListener = listener;
            P.mCheckedItems = checkedItems;
            P.mIsMultiChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setNegativeButton(CharSequence text,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mNegativeButtonText = text;
            P.mNegativeButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setNegativeButton(int textId,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mNegativeButtonText = P.mContext.getText(textId);
            P.mNegativeButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setNeutralButton(CharSequence text,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mNeutralButtonText = text;
            P.mNeutralButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setNeutralButton(int textId,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mNeutralButtonText = P.mContext.getText(textId);
            P.mNeutralButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOnCancelListener(OnCancelListener onCancelListener) {
            P.mOnCancelListener = onCancelListener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOnItemSelectedListener(
                final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener) {
            P.mOnItemSelectedListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOnKeyListener(OnKeyListener onKeyListener) {
            P.mOnKeyListener = onKeyListener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setOnPrepareListViewListener(
                OnPrepareListViewListener listener) {
            P.mOnPrepareListViewListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setPositiveButton(CharSequence text,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mPositiveButtonText = text;
            P.mPositiveButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setPositiveButton(int textId,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mPositiveButtonText = P.mContext.getText(textId);
            P.mPositiveButtonListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setRecycleOnMeasureEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            P.mRecycleOnMeasure = enabled;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setSingleChoiceItems(CharSequence[] items,
                int checkedItem, final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mItems = items;
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            P.mCheckedItem = checkedItem;
            P.mIsSingleChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setSingleChoiceItems(Cursor cursor, int checkedItem,
                String labelColumn, final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mCursor = cursor;
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            P.mCheckedItem = checkedItem;
            P.mLabelColumn = labelColumn;
            P.mIsSingleChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setSingleChoiceItems(int itemsId, int checkedItem,
                final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mItems = P.mContext.getResources().getTextArray(itemsId);
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            P.mCheckedItem = checkedItem;
            P.mIsSingleChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setSingleChoiceItems(ListAdapter adapter,
                int checkedItem, final OnClickListener listener) {
            P.mAdapter = adapter;
            P.mOnClickListener = listener;
            P.mCheckedItem = checkedItem;
            P.mIsSingleChoice = true;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTitle(CharSequence title) {
            P.mTitle = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setTitle(int titleId) {
            P.mTitle = P.mContext.getText(titleId);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setView(View view) {
            P.mView = view;
            P.mViewSpacingSpecified = false;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setView(View view, int viewSpacingLeft,
                int viewSpacingTop, int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom) {
            P.mView = view;
            P.mViewSpacingSpecified = true;
            P.mViewSpacingLeft = viewSpacingLeft;
            P.mViewSpacingTop = viewSpacingTop;
            P.mViewSpacingRight = viewSpacingRight;
            P.mViewSpacingBottom = viewSpacingBottom;
            return this;
        }

        public AlertDialog show() {
            AlertDialog dialog = create();
            dialog.show();
            return dialog;
        }
    }

    public static final int THEME_HOLO_DARK = 1;
    public static final int THEME_HOLO_LIGHT = 2;

    static int resolveDialogTheme(Context context, int resid) {
        if (resid == THEME_HOLO_DARK) {
            return R.style.Holo_Theme_Dialog_Alert;
        } else if (resid == THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) {
            return R.style.Holo_Theme_Dialog_Alert_Light;
        } else if (resid >= 0x01000000) {
            return resid;
        } else {
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.alertDialogTheme,
                    outValue, true);
            return outValue.resourceId;
        }
    }

    private final AlertController mAlert;

    protected AlertDialog(Context context) {
        this(context, false, null, resolveDialogTheme(context, 0));
    }

    protected AlertDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable,
            OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        this(context, cancelable, cancelListener,
                resolveDialogTheme(context, 0));
    }

    protected AlertDialog(Context context, boolean cancelable,
            OnCancelListener cancelListener, int theme) {
        super(context, resolveDialogTheme(context, theme));
        setCancelable(cancelable);
        setOnCancelListener(cancelListener);
        mAlert = new AlertController(context, this, getWindow());
    }

    protected AlertDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        this(context, false, null, theme);
    }

    public Button getButton(int whichButton) {
        return mAlert.getButton(whichButton);
    }

    public ListView getListView() {
        return mAlert.getListView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mAlert.installContent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (mAlert.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (mAlert.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setButton(CharSequence text, Message msg) {
        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, text, msg);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setButton(CharSequence text, final OnClickListener listener) {
        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, text, listener);
    }

    public void setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text, Message msg) {
        mAlert.setButton(whichButton, text, null, msg);
    }

    public void setButton(int whichButton, CharSequence text,
            OnClickListener listener) {
        mAlert.setButton(whichButton, text, listener, null);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setButton2(CharSequence text, Message msg) {
        setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, text, msg);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setButton2(CharSequence text, final OnClickListener listener) {
        setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, text, listener);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setButton3(CharSequence text, Message msg) {
        setButton(BUTTON_NEUTRAL, text, msg);
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void setButton3(CharSequence text, final OnClickListener listener) {
        setButton(BUTTON_NEUTRAL, text, listener);
    }

    public void setCustomTitle(View customTitleView) {
        mAlert.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);
    }

    public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
        mAlert.setIcon(icon);
    }

    public void setIcon(int resId) {
        mAlert.setIcon(resId);
    }

    public void setIconAttribute(int attrId) {
        TypedValue out = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(attrId, out, true);
        mAlert.setIcon(out.resourceId);
    }

    public void setInverseBackgroundForced(boolean forceInverseBackground) {
        mAlert.setInverseBackgroundForced(forceInverseBackground);
    }

    public void setMessage(CharSequence message) {
        mAlert.setMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        super.setTitle(title);
        mAlert.setTitle(title);
    }

    public void setView(View view) {
        mAlert.setView(view);
    }

    public void setView(View view, int viewSpacingLeft, int viewSpacingTop,
            int viewSpacingRight, int viewSpacingBottom) {
        mAlert.setView(view, viewSpacingLeft, viewSpacingTop, viewSpacingRight,
                viewSpacingBottom);
    }
}
```